# when returns wp_errors or 0 , how to set conditional tag

Tags: posts

I am making front-end post submit. and I almost completed. 
I want to redirect to specific page after submitting post in front-end successfully.

I am using this function.

```
wp_insert_post( array $postarr, bool $wp_error = false )
```

and this returns :

> The post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on failure.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
if( !$post_id || ?? ){ 
    wp_redirect( site_url('/compledted/') );
}
```

This is my code to make.I just want to redirect when submitting post is successfully finished. but I exactly don't know how to set if(  ) conditions. 
can you help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: the value `0` or `WP_Error` depends of the argument `$wp_error`. then you test `if (0 === $post_id) {// error}` or `if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {// error}`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to use the code you recommend, but how can I test an error? how can I set errors occur?

Answer (score 1):

you can test an error like that

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data, TRUE);

if (is_wp_error($post_id)) { 
    // there is an error

}

wp_redirect(site_url('/compledted/'));
exit();
```

Comment: I mean, which situation makes errors. I can check if the wp_insert_post() succeed or not. But I don't know this works well when errors occur. So I want to check, when errors occur.